# How to traverse through FIFO/RT list of processes in kernel

Tags: c, process, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduler

I am trying to modify the current FIFO/RT scheduler in the kernel. I successfully changed in the kernel, through a system call, the process's current scheduler (from fair/NORMAL) to FIFO. I do this in `core.c`

Now I have to iterate through the processes list, pick the process based on the `tgid` field in `task_struct` and put a particular process in front of the queue to be processed next. How can I do this? Which system calls/function help me do this?

**EDIT**: I have already figured it out how to do the same for CFS in the Red-Black tree. I am using the `rb_first` and `rb_next` functions. I need similar functions for data structures in FIFO.

Comment: It might help if you could post some of your existing code.  Also, by FIFO do you mean the RT scheduler?